# Running Maven PMD locally using Sonar ruleset

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, sonarqube, pmd

I'm attempting to run pmd locally using Maven. In project I run

```
mvn jxr:jxr pmd:pmd
```

but receive error :

```
net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'rulesets/basic.xml' for rule 'UnusedNullCheckInEquals'.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL and is on the CLASSPATH
```

Here is a snippet of the rules file which was exported :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset>
  <rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml/UnusedNullCheckInEquals">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

I've updated pom file to reference custom ruleset :

```
          <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <linkXref>true</linkXref>
            <rulesets>
                <ruleset>c:\\pmd\\export.xml</ruleset>
            </rulesets>

        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

To export the ruleset so can run pmd locally using Maven is it required to export this file (basic.xml) & all other xml files which together comprise the "Sonar Way" quality profile ? If so where can these files be accessed on Sonar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access thru "Quality Profiles > Sonar Way > Permalinks > PMD", although, I think "Sonar Way" pmd rules are empty by default (all rules disabled).

Also, have in mind that version 3.2 of `maven-pmd-plugin` looks for rules not in `rulesets` but in `rulesets/java`, so you might have to replace that path in the exported file (at least the file that you get with Sonar 4.2).

Finally, I would recommend not using a hardcoded path to reference the ruleset file, use something like:

```
<ruleset>${project.basedir}/rules/pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, the rules file at "Quality Profiles > Sonar Way > Permalinks > PMD" references other files such as <rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml/UnusedNullCheckInEquals"> but I'm not sure where to locate these files. You appear to suggest that these referenced files have been custom added and are not part of default Sonar setup ?

Comment: Please, refer to this documentation of the `maven-pmd-plugin`: [Using Rule Sets](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html) " These rule sets are **bundled** in the PMD code analysis tool" and "Starting with PMD 5.0 and Maven PMD Plugin 3.0 the paths to the bundled rule sets for the Java language were **changed** from /rulesets/xyz.xml to /rulesets/java/xyz.xml"